# Evitar que un textarea se pueda redimensionar

Tags: html, css, textarea

Tengo un formulario con un `textarea` del comentario, y quiero evitar que se pueda redimensionar horizontalmente, solo verticalmente. De momento yo lo hacia dando estilos a un input para que fuese más grande, pero no se podia redimensionar, y eso era un problema. Dejo el código:

```html
<form action="respuesta.php" method="post">
    <label for="nombre">Nombre</label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="la primera mayúscula" style="padding:7px;" id="nombre">
    <br><br>
    <label for="comentario">Comentario</label>
    <br>
    <textarea rows="10" cols="50" placeholder="Inserte su comentario" id="comentario"></textarea>
    <br><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Enviar">
</form>
```

Me falta el `css` para evitar que se pueda redimensionar el `textarea`. Hay alguna solución o tendré que usar `input` "grande" en sustituto a `textarea`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplemente le das con CSS la propiedad `resize: vertical;`. Por defecto es `both` y tambien podes usar `horizontal`

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_resize.php

```css
textarea {
  border: 2px solid;
  padding: 20px; 
  width: 300px;
  resize: vertical;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <textarea>
      Resize
    </textarea>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Solo hay 4 propiedades de `resize`: `both`, `vertical`, `horizontal` y `none`, verdad?

Comment: @Euricky999 ademas de esas podes usar initial e inherit, en el link a la documentación están todas explicadas